# Android 13 takes half an hour to connect to mobile network

Tags: mobile-network, android-13, fairphone-4

I have a fairphone 4, and when I restart it, it takes about half an hour or more to get network connection.
Even if I set the phone to manually pick a network operator, the phone is unable to connect.

Once the network is connected, the phone works perfectly fine, including 5G internet.

Wifi and bluetooth work fine. I can connect as soon as the phone get's restarted.

How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Assuming you have a good network -check performance in safe mode. If it works fine, it means some installed app is causing it. If the problem persists , it could be a network or phone hardware issue. Try with a SIM of a different provider